# React HoC abstraction layer

Tags: reactjs

I have to do a large rewrite for work. One part of it is an api that has changed. It is provided by a HoC. Instead of rewriting every instance of this to the new api, I plan on just writing an abstraction layer. So, withOldHoC would provide the old api with the new functionality withNewHoC.

code would look something like this,

```
  import React from "react";
import { withTracker } from "@SomeCompany/react-tracker";

let withTracking = ComponentToTrack => {
  return props => {
    return <ComponentToTrack {...props} tracking={props.tracker} />;
  };
};

export default withTracker(withTracking);
```

I am aware this is wrong. Thoughts on how any of you would write this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An option to do this would be using context. If your application is using function components you could create a context provider wrapping your router and the access it with a hook on your components.

```
import { useContext, createContext } from 'react'

export const ApiContext = createContext({
  api: {
     ...your api schema here     
  }
})

export const useApi = () => useContext(ApiContext)
```

then is as easy as importing your hook and using your api call

Comment: I can play around with this and see. Thanks!

Comment: You need to wrap your router with <ApiContext.Provider value={yourApiObject}>. Let me know if you have any questions. Remember also to check the React docs regarding context and hooks and, if it solves your issue, mark as the solution :)

Comment: Hrm. I still need to have access to the tracker prop so I can transform it into `tracking`. Won't have that in the context creation step. :(

Comment: Also consider using a library like redial to handle all the calls that need to be called before the component starts rendering. Is a bit cleaner than using useEffect or ComponentDidMount. Good luck!

Comment: Do the same with the tracking. Create a tracking context on top of the Api context so that your Api Layer can see your Tracking layer but not the other way round. This is called "Layering" (duh) and its quite useful to avoid dependencies;